# A connection between a PDDM and the agent was closed. [TaskManager.cpp:168]

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, event-log

I was trying to find a solution for issue,,that is one Service repeatadly going on restart which is making the issue.When i checked the event log
i can see one waring before the restart occurs

Warning is

"**The description for Event ID ( 1 ) in Source ( ZENworks Patch Management Agent ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: A connection between a PDDM and the agent was closed. [TaskManager.cpp:168]."**

We know  PDDM.exe is a process that runs in the background on the agent machine. It handles deployments notification. The agent will log this message when PDDM.exe exits from memory. The following events will cause PDDM.exe to exit from memory: User logging off, computer shutting down, PDDM.exe gets killed from task manager..

But i dont know how to proceed with this issue,Can any one help me regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two options one is Reinstall the application,other is reboot the OS

Any other options?